# Converting bullets Text to HTML using VBA function Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have lots of products which have description including bullets, which I want to convert it to html form excel file.

Description of product be like in one cell :

```
•   Our aim is to be devoted to building a sustainable future. 
•   We are keen to preserve the human being and its environment.
•   It is best for all skin types
```

some macro code I have tried is like:

```
Sub aTest()
    Dim rCell As Range, spl As Variant, i As Long
    
    For Each rCell In Selection
        spl = Split(rCell, Chr(10))
        For i = LBound(spl) To UBound(spl)
            spl(i) = Chr(60) & "li" & Chr(62) & spl(i) & Chr(60) & "/li" & Chr(62)
        Next i
        rCell = Join(spl, Chr(10))
    Next rCell
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 200
    Selection.EntireRow.AutoFit
    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

this code gives me output including bullets within it:

[image]

**Expected:**

```
<li> Our aim is to be devoted to building a sustainable future. </li>
<li> We are keen to preserve the human being and its environment.</li>
<li> It is best for all skin types</li>
```

Could anyone please help me get this correct, as I do not have any idea of VB.
Moreover, it would be great to have Function rather than macro.

Thanks

**Update:** I have this whole content within one cell and want it to convert to html together. Is that possible?

```
BIODERMA is a brand of NAOS, the world’s number 1 cosmetic company. BIODERMA has been dedicated to skin health for 40 years and has pioneered many breakthroughs in dermatological care. We are a company that provides high-quality skin care products developed by medical professionals with the absolute highest safety standards. 
Key Features:
•   Our aim is to be devoted to building a sustainable future. 
•   We are keen to preserve the human being and its environment.
•   It is best for all skin types
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Function ConvertBulletToHTML(argInput As String) As String
    Dim cleanArr() As String
    cleanArr = Split(argInput, vbLf)
        
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(cleanArr)
        If Instr(cleanArr(i), Chr(149)) <> 0 Then
              cleanArr(i) = Replace(cleanArr(i), Chr(149), vbNullString)
              cleanArr(i) = "<li>" & Trim(cleanArr(i)) & "</li>"
        End If
    Next i
        
    ConvertBulletToHTML = "<div>" & Join(cleanArr, vbLf) & "</div>"
End Function
```

This is the output:

```
<div><li>Our aim is to be devoted to building a sustainable future.</li> 
<li>We are keen to preserve the human being and its environment.</li> 
<li>It is best for all skin types</li></div>
```

And output for the updated question:

```
<div>BIODERMA is a brand of NAOS, the world’s number 1 cosmetic company. BIODERMA has been dedicated to skin health for 40 years and has pioneered many breakthroughs in dermatological care. We are a company that provides high-quality skin care products developed by medical professionals with the absolute highest safety standards.
Key Features:
<li>Our aim is to be devoted to building a sustainable future.</li>
<li>We are keen to preserve the human being and its environment.</li>
<li>It is best for all skin types</li></div>
```

Remove the Trim in the for loop if you do not want it trimmed.

Note: `vbLf` is the same as `Chr(10)` so you can just use the built-in constant.

Comment: this works fine for me, but a little change. Updated my question.

Comment: @Ankita You did not specify what's the desired outcome for the updated question, you only want `li` tag for the bullet points and left the rest alone?

Comment: may be some div as a parent node.

Comment: @Ankita Updated (but not tested as I have no access to PC at the moment). It should now apply `li` tag to line that has bullet point and leave the rest alone. It will also surround the entire content with `div` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
spli(i) = Replace(spli(i), Chr(149), "")
```

You must check if it is actually `Chr(149)` and change it to something else if it is not.
Other way - assuming it is the first character in your `spli(i)`

```
spli(i) = Right(spli(i), Len(spli(i)) - 1)
```

This must be applied before adding html tags.